# two kind of date formats data loaded on mysql field

Tags: mysql

A person developed a Mysql data base to migrate from access for an aplication, however, the dates in Access were saved as 'd-m-Y'. When this person loaded the access data, it was storaged in the original format, however, the new data is loaded in Mysql date format 'Y-m-d' in the same fields.

What can I do to uptade the historical data to change its format from 'd-m-Y' to 'Y-m-d'?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is the **only** data in the table from the legacy table, or has new data been added to it since import? What sort of solution are you looking for? How do you identify legacy data? etc

Comment: It has been added new data. The old data is only reconginzable because it has a different format

Comment: You've said that the old format is `d-m-Y` but is the year stored as a two or four digit number? If the former, there's not a lot you can do for dates from 2001 onwards. If the latter, a simple `update` with some text extraction/concatenation  functions should sort your data out. Again, what have you tried so far?

Comment: You have to be a bit more precise when telling us _“the legacy data can be recognized by its format”_. What about `10-11-12`? Is it “Nov 10 in 2012” or “Nov 12 in 2010”? You see? In case you meant `dd-mm-YYYY` and `YYYY-mm-dd` then there's light at the end of the tunnel.

Comment: To give you a hint: dates in the format `dd-mm-YYYY` can be found with `select d from T1 where d regexp '^[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{4}$';`. Now try yourself and combine this knowledge with [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).